# How to create Oracle trigger that deletes/updates only some rows from the original query?

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have a table:

```
create table projects(pid int,name char(10),active int);
insert into projects values(1,'aa',1);
insert into projects values(2,'bb',0);
```

and I want to create a trigger that doesn't allow to delete a project that is active (active=1).
So, for the command:
`delete from projects where pid in (1,2)`
only row with pid=2 will be deleted and the row with pid=1 **will not be deleted**.
And no error will be reported (only a warning maybe?).

In SQL Server I am doing it like that:

```
create trigger nondel on projects instead of DELETE
as
delete from projects where pid in (select pid from deleted where active=0)
end
```

So "instead of" trigger and only rows that fulfill both delete condition and active=0 condition are deleted.

In Oracle I tried a "for each" trigger:

```
create trigger nondel before delete on projects
for each row
when :old.active=1
begin
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20502, 'Active rows cannot be deleted!');
end
```

but RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR aborts the whole transaction and nothing is deleted.
My question is: Is it possible to declare a 'for each row' trigger with a code that when a condition is fulfilled does not not delete the row but doesn't raise any error either, just continues with subsequent rows? Or maybe a statement trigger would be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is totally against the Oracle architecture. It is fine to block an action, as you showed with your `RAISE_EXCEPTION` trigger, but it is absolutely unusual to suppress an action without an error message.

Theoretically, it could be implemented with an `INSTEAD OF` trigger, but they work only on views:

```
create view forcefield as select * from projects;

create or replace trigger tiud_forcefield
  instead of insert or update or delete on forcefield
  for each row
begin
  if INSERTING then
    INSERT INTO projects(pid, name, active) VALUES (:new.pid, :new.name, :new.active);
  end if;

  if UPDATING then
    UPDATE projects SET pid=:new.pid, name=:new.name, active=:new.active
     WHERE pid = :old.pid;
  end if;

  if DELETING then
    if :old.active = 0 then
      DELETE FROM projects WHERE pid = :old.pid;
    end if;
  end if;
end;
/
```

The protecting view has all the rows of the table:

```
select * from forcefield;
PID NAME ACTIVE
1   aa   1
2   bb   0
```

If you delete an inactive project, it works fine:

```
delete from forcefield where pid=2;
1 row deleted.

select * from forcefield;
PID NAME ACTIVE
1   aa   1
```

However, if you try to delete an active project, it still claims that it has deleted one row, but didn't. Yikes!

```
delete from forcefield where pid=1;
1 row deleted.

select * from forcefield;
PID NAME ACTIVE
1   aa   1
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea, even if it is not exactly what I wanted. But you are right that creating a trigger that *silently* reduces the number of rows deleted may be a "maintenance headache" according to Tom Kyte. Probably we will find another solution...